# Xamarin.Forms List view with caching strategy recycle element won't refresh visible elements

Tags: listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a project in Xamarin.Forms which contains a listView bound to an ObservableCollection.

The listView contains cells, each with a label and a switch. I have two buttons above that list : Select all & Unselect all. Those buttons should toggle all the switches accordingly (and hopefully update the UI state of the switch) : Select all should refresh my listView with all switches toggled ON and Unselect all should refresh my listView with all switches toggled OFF.

I also have a caching strategy on that list set to "Recycle element".

The interesting part is : When I click on 'Select all' or 'Unselect all' button, the upper part of the listView (which is visible on screen) is not refresh **BUT** when I scroll down the listView, the new generated cells are updated since they are new due to the caching strategy. Also when I scroll back up, the old cells are also refreshed since they were recycled.

How can I refresh the switch state in my listView **without** scrolling it ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not an Android then my answer probably isn't relevant.
We had the exact same problem in Xamarin.Forms with a listview with text and a switch on Android, turns out there's a known Android bug where the listview isn't refreshed, we've ended up implementing the workaround given (sorry I don't have the url for where this answer was originally found, as I didn't find it).

```
                <x:Arguments>
                <ListViewCachingStrategy>
                    <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ListViewCachingStrategy" iOS="RecycleElement" Android="RetainElement"/>
                </ListViewCachingStrategy>
            </x:Arguments>
```

The workaround was to turn off caching on Android, I think the bug only applied to recent versions of the Android OS, but we didn't bother differentiating.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the problem occurs in both platform. I already tried to disable Recycle element but the list still doesn't refresh AND is slow :/.

Comment: I found a workaround, I disabled the recycle element and used this method to refresh the list on my own ObservableCollection extended class.

`public void AddAndRemoveItem(T item)
        {
            this.Items.Add(item);
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
            this.Items.Remove(item);
            this.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }`